# Run a Firebase Testlab test from node server

Tags: node.js, heroku, firebase-test-lab

we have a Heroku hosted nodejs server that servers a rest API. We want to add an endpoint to which we can upload an APK and have the server spin up a test for us on Firebase.

I can't seem to find any nodejs server side libraries from Google to help me achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your nodes server, you could call [Cloud Testing API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/reference/testing/rest) directly to start a test. Test execution results can be retrieved with [Cloud Tool Results API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/reference/toolresults/rest). Both of these two APIs are public API and there is [Nodejs client support](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client).